# Turn off auto centering with JQuery scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollable

With the JQuery scrollable widget.  If you click the top, it scrolls to the middle.  Is there any way to leave the "clicked" elements within the widget where they are when clicked?

```
[Position1]
[Position2]
[Position3]
[Position4]
[Position5]
```

For example, if I click Position5, I want it to stay in its place, NOT scroll itself into Position 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why use a scollable widget if nothing should happen, when clicking an element?

Comment: What plugin are you using exactly?

Comment: We have custom events that happened when you click.  There is an issue with it trying to auto center when i click one of the elements.

This is what i was using:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html
And the answer to the question is the library just didnt work for what we wanted so we created a custom one from scratch.  Its much lighter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter `clickable:false` to the scrollable initializer:

```
$("#scroller").scrollable({clickable:false});
```